# pseudo-complex routes in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes, custom-routes

I'm trying to make some nice simple routes in Rails 3 with 2 custom matchers which assume the root :id will be a city and :city_id/:id will be a place... it seems to work fine except when trying to edit.

Ie.

```
root_url/countries/france
root_url/paris/some_place
root_url/paris
```

Here's my code to be more precise.

```
resources :countries do
  resources :cities
end

resources :cities do
  resources :places, :reviews
end

match ':id' => 'cities#show', :as => :city, :method => :get
match ':city_id/:id' => 'places#show', :as => :city_place, :method => :get
```

That seems to work perfectly accept when I try to edit records.  The html is as below:

```
<% form_for @city do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Produces:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/kiev" class="edit_city" id="edit_city_3581" method="post">
```

Which would only work if it were:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/cities/kiev" class="edit_city" id="edit_city_3581" method="post">
```

I know I could simply provide a more advanced form_for route explicitly to get around this, but I'm wondering if there's something better to do in my routes.rb to make my life easier rather than patching?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you renamed your custom routes like this and let normal routes handle edit etc.

```
get ':id' => 'cities#show', :as => :city_shortcut
get ':city_id/:id' => 'places#show', :as => :city_place_shortcut
```

Comment: I thought about that, and that may be the way to go.  I'm just wondering if it's better that way or renaming the form_for routes.  If I use :city_shortcut I'll have to change all the link_to, etc. vs form_for.  I'm looking for pros / cons.

Comment: I would keep the default behaviour for resources and only modify the bits and pieces that are required for this custom enhancement. Otherwise everything becomes custom and harder to follow.